# Is readinessprobe used amidst rolling deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, readinessprobe

In the below  yaml syntax:

```
      readinessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /index.html
          port: 80
        initialDelaySeconds: 3
        timeoutSeconds: 3
        periodSeconds: 10
        failureThreshold: 3
```

---

Readiness probe is used during initial deployments of Pod.

1. For rolling out new version of application, using rolling deployment strategy,
   Is readiness probe used for rolling deployment?
2. `path` & `port` field allows to input url & port number of a specific service, but not dependent service. how to verify, if dependent service is also ready?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> using rolling deployment strategy, Is readiness probe used for rolling deployment?

Yes, the new version of Pods is rolled out and older Pods are not terminated until the new version has Pods in *ready* state.

E.g. if you roll out a new version, that has a bug so that the Pods does not become ready - the old Pods will still be running and the traffic is only routed to the *ready* old Pods.

Also, if you don't specify a *readinessProbe*, the *process* status is used, e.g. a *process* that terminates will not be seen as *ready*.

> how to verify, if dependent service is also ready?

You can configure a custom *readinessProbe*, e.g. a http-endpoint on `/healtz` and it is up to you what logic you want to use in the implementation of that endpoint. A http response code of 2xx is seen as *ready*.